# Error with Ajax Jquery file upload in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to upload file using ajax in codeigniter framework.
But i got error message 'You did not select a file to upload.'
Please check this code

View

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file_upload">
<input type="file" id="file-input" name="file">
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$("#file-input").change(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#file_upload')[0]);    
    $.ajax({
        url : 'do_upload',
        data: formData,
        type:'POST',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //  dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

controller

```
public  function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
        echo  $this->upload->display_errors() ; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Uploaded";
    }
}
```

Comment: with your url part `url : 'do_upload'` try` url : "<?php echo base_url('controller-name/do_upload');?>"`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the URL is pointing to a page or function that you have created. Try this: -

```js
$("#file-input").change(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#file_upload')[0]);    
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url('do_upload'); ?>',
        data: formData,
        type:'POST',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //  dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong in AJAX request

It should be `url : '<?php echo site_url('controllerName/do_upload'); ?>',`

Also use

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'file_upload')); ?>
```

for form opening AND

```
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

for form closing

Let me know if you require any further help